# Auto Start OpenVPN in shell on a Jail Broken iOS device

Tags: ios, jailbreak, openvpn, launchd

I have an iPad Air 2 that is Jail-broken.

I currently have OpenVPN installed with a shell version of openvpn:

OpenVPN 2.3-alpha1 i686-apple-darwin10 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO2] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110522-1 (2.2.0)] built on May 28 2012

I am trying to set OpenVPN's command line executable as a Launch Daemon so this it autoconnects to my OpenVPN server after a reboot. This needs to be super automated so that I can have the ipad mounted in a place where I am not near physically.

I have created the following plist file at /Library/LaunchDaemons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd";>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>org.openvpn</string>
<key>OnDemand</key>
<false/>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/usr/local/sbin/openvpn</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>openvpn</string>
<string>—-cd</string>
<string>/var/mobile/Documents/Configurations/bigfoot.ovpn</string>
<string>--config</string>
<string>bigfoot.ovpn</string>
<string>--auto-proxy</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>TimeOut</key>
<integer>90</integer>
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/etc/openvpn</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Upon reboot the process does not seem to start and I dont see anything in the "dmesg" any direction to help me out would be great.

I would use the OpenVPN GUI app but it requires me to toggle the connection manually.

If someone has another idea how I can achieve this I am open to suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going in the right direction. `launchd` daemons is the way to go.

Several things does not look right in your plist:

1. `OnDemand` is deprecated, you need to use `KeepAlive` instead. In your case just set it to `true`
2. Usually you don't mix `Program` and `ProgramArguments`. They basically do the same thing, only latter can do more. You better off with  `ProgramArguments` only
3. The actual `ProgramArguments` look wrong. Remember, those are program arguments that will be passed to your openvpn process. They should look something like this

   ```
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array>
   <string>/usr/local/sbin/openvpn</string>
   <string>--config</string>
   <string>/var/mobile/Documents/Configurations/bigfoot.ovpn</string>
   <string>--auto-proxy</string>
   </array>
   ```

   And no `Program` needed

Now, when you want to debug `launchd` daemon you don't need to reboot every time you need to test it. You can use this:

`launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openvpn.plist`

It will load your daemon into `launchd` and launch it. If something goes wrong he will tell you. When you need to reload your plist (made some changes) you do:

`launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openvpn.plist`

to stop the daemon and unload it from `launchd` and then

`launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.openvpn.plist`